# Using `|` when instantiating a new struct

Tags: elixir

The following code is copy-pasted from 'Elixir in Action' published by Manning.

```
defmodule TodoList do

  defstruct auto_id: 1, entries: HashDict.new

  def new, do: %TodoList{}

  def add(
    %TodoList{entries: entries, auto_id: auto_id} = todo_list,
    entry) do
      entry = Map.put(entry, :id, auto_id)
      new_entries = HashDict.put(entries, auto_id, entry)
      %TodoList{ todo_list |
        entries: new_entries,
        auto_id: auto_id + 1
      }
    end

end
```

I do not understand the use of `todo_list |` at the end of the `add` function when creating the new `TodoList`.  I tried removing it altogether and couldn't really see a difference in the result.  Can anyone explain to me what it is achieving?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is shorthand syntax for updating a map:

```
iex> map = %{foo: "bar"}
%{foo: "bar"}

iex> map = %{map | foo: "quux"}
%{foo: "quux"}
```

Note that unlike [`Map.put/3`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Map.html#put/3), you can only update existing keys, which gives you some safety. It behaves more like Erlang's [`:maps.update/3`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/maps.html#update-3).

```
iex> map = %{map | baz: "quux"}
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    (stdlib) :maps.update(:baz, "quux", %{foo: "bar"})
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:255: anonymous fn/2 in :erl_eval.expr/5
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1261: :lists.foldl/3
```

Also note that structs like your `%TodoList{}` are really just maps, so all of this works exactly the same way with structs.

Now, because you are setting *all valid keys of the struct* it makes no difference whether you put the `todo_list |` in there or not for now. However, if a new key is added to the struct, your `add` function might not work as expected any more, discarding the other keys. So I'd recommend you leave it in there.